# Performance tool for client API and Middle tier testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, performance-testing

I need to test my client API and Middle Tier performance. C# API with ASP Web Api Middle Tier.
I want to use something like NPerf to be able to write tests in VS and get execution statistics. But NPerf doesn't provide raw Middle Tier performance (this can be some sniffer which tracks all HTTP requests).

Comment: What is it that you want? A tool which can test performance of your application (like load runer)? Or you want to know which tool can help you to analyze your codes performance? In any case I did not understand how Nunit is going to help?

Comment: The tools that you can use are VS In-build performance analysis tool, Ants memory profiler, dynatrace